# syntax needed for conditional hyperlink column

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement, hyperlink, conditional-statements

Ok, I have a `vendors` table with a column called `rate_vendor` which contains a hyperlink to the `rate_vendor_add` page. It sets default vendor as the vendor from where the link was clicked. Each user can only rate each vendor one time but can edit that ranking so to achieve this I set a dual column primary key for the vendor_ratings table. The 2 columns are `vendor` and `user`. If a particular user has not rated a particular vendor the "rate vendor" link works fine, but what I need is a conditional hyperlink that links to the `vendor_ratings_edit` page instead of the `vendor_ratings_add` page if that vendor has already been rated by that user. Below is the code I use for the "rate vendor" link:

```
$value = "< a href='vendor_ratings_add.php?Vendor=" . $data["Vendor"] . "'>Rate this vendor</a>"
```

This would be the "Edit Rating" link:

```
< a href='vendor_ratings_edit.php?Vendor=" . $data["Vendor"] . "'>Edit rating</a>
```

I need help with the syntax needed for the IF ELSE statement. Can anybody lead me in the right direction?

Comment: Do you have a boolean variable already, `$hasRated` or something? If not you need to first make your db call to figure that out

Comment: I don't. How would I achieve this?

Comment: You could do a simple select on the vendor_ratings table. If the combination of vendorId and userId exists, the user must have rated the vendor at some time.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, do an SQL query to find if the user has rated that vendor or not.

```
SELECT id from vendor_ratings WHERE vendorid = x AND userid = y
```

If a row is returned, then we now know which link to display.

Assuming we made a boolean called `$hasRated`, all you'd need to do would be this:

```
$href = ($hasRated) 
    ? "< a href='vendor_ratings_add.php?Vendor=" . $data["Vendor"] . "'>Rate this vendor</a>"
    : "< a href='vendor_ratings_edit.php?Vendor=" . $data["Vendor"] . "'>Edit rating</a>"
```

Comment: I understand your logic. What I don't understand is how to make a boolean for each vendor and each user. Using the select statement above would tell you if a rating exist for one vendor by one user. I have 500 vendors and dozens of users.

Comment: Just see if a row is returned `$hasRated = count($result) ? true : false;`

Comment: So I would need to do this for 500 vendors: SELECT id from vendor_ratings WHERE vendorid = x AND userid = y

Comment: replacing x and y with the correcty ids, and putting the correct table name in, yes

Comment: ok, this code works:

$rs = DB::Query("select * from `vendor ratings` 
WHERE 
(`Vendor`='" . $data["Vendor"] . "')
And
(User='".$_SESSION["User"]."')
");
If ( $data = $rs->fetchAssoc() )
$value = "<a href='vendor_ratings_edit.php?Vendor=" . $data["Vendor"] . "'>Edit rating</a>";
else
$value = "<a href='vendor_ratings_add.php?Vendor=" . $data["Vendor"] . "'>Rate this vendor</a>";

The problem is that the "edit rating" link opens the vendor_rating_edit page defaulted to correct vendor but "rate vendor" link doesn't. Both "<a href=" statements are identical.

Comment: are you saying that the add rating link never appears, it's always the edit link?

Comment: It was. Fixed now. ( $data = $rs->fetchAssoc() ) syntax was wrong here.